# Does hyperparameter tuning of Decision Tree then use it in Adaboost individually vs Simultaneously yield the same results?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees, hyperparameter-tuning, gridsearchcv, adaboost

So, my predicament here is as follows, I performed hyperparameter tuning on a standalone Decision Tree classifier, and I got the best results, now comes the turn of Standalone Adaboost, but here is where my problem lies, if I use the Tuned Decision Tree from earlier as a base_estimator in Adaboost, then I perform hyperparameter tuning on Adaboost only, will it yield the same results as trying to perform hyperparameter tuning on untuned Adaboost and untuned Decision Tree as a base_estimator simultaneously, where I try the hyperparameters of both Adaboost and Decision Tree together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, generally optimizing two parts of a modeling pipeline separately will not work as well as searching over all the parameters simultaneously.

In your particular case, this is easier to see: the optimal single tree will probably be much deeper than the optimal trees in an AdaBoost ensemble.  A single tree (probably) needs to split quite a bit to avoid being dramatically underfit, whereas AdaBoost generally performs best with "weak learners", and in particular often a "decision stump", i.e. a depth-1 tree, is selected.

Comment: When we use another classifier as a base estimator for AdaBoost e.g. `AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator = dtree_model)`, do we not use AdaBoost's own `n_estimators` and `learning_rate?` params?